# Tossing two coins 100 times each, what is the probability for same number of heads?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I know it's a binomial distribution, but haven't been able to figure out how to do it. Well there'll be two identical distributions, and then I'm not sure how to proceed. I could multiply them, couldn't I?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you know that the distribution is binomial, how can you think to apply that to this problem?

Comment: Well there'll be two identical distributions, and then I'm not sure how to proceed. I could multiply them, couldn't i?

Answer (score 2):

There are $2^{200}$ possible outcomes of the coin flips. Of these, $\binom{100}n^2$ of them have both coins showing heads $n$ times each, so the number of outcomes we want to count is
$$\sum_{n=0}^{100}\binom{100}n^2$$
which is known to be equal to the central binomial coefficient ([OEIS A984](https://oeis.org/A000984))
$$\binom{200}{100}$$
The probability we want is thus
$$\frac{\binom{200}{100}}{2^{200}}$$